# How to merge two data frames by matching two numeric columns with a +-5 range?

Tags: r

I have two data frames as below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(chrom = c(1,1,3,6,6),
                  chromStart = c(15433, 1959,34205,35043, 77456),
                  chromEnd = c(15700, 2001,36245,36245,78469), 
                  id = c('aaad', 'dfk', 'bb', 'llk', 'ie9o'))

df2 <- data.frame(chrom = c(1,1,5,1,6),
                  chromStart2 = c(15433, 1961,34205,1962, 77456),
                  chromEnd2 = c(15700, 2002,36245,1999,78480))
```

I'd like to merge the two data frames by matching `chrom == chrom, chromStart = between(chromStart2 -5, chromStart2 +5)` and `chromEnd = between(chromEnd2 -5, chromEnd2 +5)`. What I've tried is:

```
library(dplyr)
colnames(df2) <- c('chrom','chromStart', 'chromEnd')
merged <- inner_join(df1,df2)
```

However, that only matches the exact `chromStart` and `chromEnd`, in our case only `aaad` matches. I'd like to give it a range of plus or minus so that `dfk` matches as well. My actual dataframes are 260000 rows and 179000 rows, so I would prefer a memory efficient way if possible. Here are the results I'm looking for:

```
data.frame(chrom = c(1,1,1),
           chromStart = c(15433, 1959,1959),
           chromEnd = c(15700, 2001,2001), 
           id = c('aaad', 'dfk', 'dfk'),
           chromStart2 = c(15433, 1961,1962),
           chromEnd2 = c(15700, 2002,1999))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better/more efficient ways, but these should work.

A `dplyr` approach: create two temporary logic vectors based on your conditions, then `filter`s based on those meeting both conditions, then drops (`select`) the temporary columns:

```
merged <- inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(
    inStart = chromStart >= chromStart2 - 5 & chromStart <= chromStart2 + 5,
    inEnd = chromEnd >= chromEnd2 - 5 & chromEnd <= chromEnd + 5) %>%
  filter(inStart, inEnd) %>%
  select(-inStart, -inEnd)

### or in one `mutate` command:
# merged <- inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
#   mutate(inrows  =  (chromStart >= chromStart2 - 5 & chromStart <= #chromStart2 + 5) &
#       (chromEnd >= chromEnd2 - 5 & chromEnd <= chromEnd + 5)) %>%
#   filter(inrows) %>%
#   select(-inrows)
```

Output:

```
#   chrom chromStart chromEnd   id chromStart2 chromEnd2
# 1     1      15433    15700 aaad       15433     15700
# 2     1       1959     2001  dfk        1961      2002
# 3     1       1959     2001  dfk        1962      1999
```

And check to ensure it meets final desired data exactly:

```
all.equal(merged,
          data.frame(chrom = c(1,1,1),
           chromStart = c(15433, 1959,1959),
           chromEnd = c(15700, 2001,2001), 
           id = c('aaad', 'dfk', 'dfk'),
           chromStart2 = c(15433, 1961,1962),
           chromEnd2 = c(15700, 2002,1999))
)
# [1] TRUE
```

A `base R` approach: subset the data by identifying the rows that meet the same conditions

```
base1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "chrom")

base_merged <- base1[(base1$chromStart >= base1$chromStart2 - 5 & base1$chromStart <= base1$chromStart2 + 5) &
        (base1$chromEnd >= base1$chromEnd2 - 5 & base1$chromEnd <= base1$chromEnd + 5),]
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works well on the data in the question. However, there's a memory allocation problem with the real data. Could you please tell me a good way to do this on a large dataset. I was thinking: split the data by chrom, match/merge, then rbind?

Comment: Hi @purple1437! Not 100% sure since I cant test the speed, but you could try to do what you described here (split, filter, etc) in base R with - `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df3, df3$chrom), function(x){
  x[(x$chromStart >= x$chromStart2 - 5 & x$chromStart <= x$chromStart2 + 5) &
          (x$chromEnd >= x$chromEnd2 - 5 & x$chromEnd <= x$chromEnd + 5),]
}))` - test that on your data and see if it will be faster? Note `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "chrom")`

Comment: Thanks. I have attempted splitting both dataframes and doing it by each chrom, but still running into memory issues. For chrom 1, I have 27000 rows df1 and 16000 rows df2. If I merge or inner_join, 430000000 rows. Is there any way to do this without merging?

Comment: @purple1437 hmm I'm sorry I'm not being more helpful! There may be a way - but first i may need a little more info: does `id` matter at all in this process?

Comment: Not at all! You've been absolutely helpful.  The id doesn't matter. It's only present in df1 and I can match it later after processing. Also, the no. of rows for df1 and df2 is different: nrow(df1) > nrow(df2)